# Amplify + Cognito signup trigger create document in lambda

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-documentdb, aws-amplify-cli

I am using amplify auth and have a table in documentdb managing user profile information. I want to be able to create a document in dynamodb on signup with the cognitoIdentityId as a field so I can query for it later.

I was hoping I could handle this in a trigger on the cognito pool but I cannot get access to the identity inside my lambda function as it doesn't appear to be on the event.

Is it possible to get access to the id so I can create my document on the trigger or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is too broad and not specific enough to answer nor is it about coding.

Comment: My question boils down to is it possible to get access to the cognitoIdentityId inside of a lambda function (code). I don't think this is too broad, the question is tagged in all things aws so this should be very clear to anyone with knowledge of aws that it is code related.